# ¿Cómo añado una restricción a mi código?

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en este mundo de la programación y por diversión hice un código que realiza el sorteo de la fase de grupos de la Copa Libertadores (2023) que consiste en tomar un equipo de cada bombo, y asignarlos a un grupo. Son 4 bombos de 8 equipos cada uno y se deben rellenar 8 grupos de 4 equipos, mi código realiza este proceso, sin embargo, los que conozcan del tema saben que existe una restricción fundamental a la hora de asignar los equipos, y es que no se pueden asignar dos equipos de misma nacionalidad en un mismo grupo, esta restricción se omite si alguno de los dos equipos en cuestión proviene de una fase previa o play-off, por ejemplo, Alianza Lima pertenece al bombo 3 y Sporting Cristal al bombo 4, ambos son equipos peruanos, por regla no se podrían alinear en un mismo grupo, pero debido a que Sporting Cristal llegó a fase de grupos a través de fases previas, sería apto para estar junto a Alianza Lima o Melgar (también club peruano) en un mismo grupo.

A continuación les presentaré mi código, puede que no sea para nada eficiente o bonito, repito que soy nuevo y estoy practicando por mero gusto. Me gustaría poder añadir la restricción que mencioné al principio, y la excepción a dicha restricción, pero no se me ocurre cómo :(

```
static ArrayList<String> grupoA = new ArrayList<String>(4);
static ArrayList<String> grupoB = new ArrayList<String>(4);
static ArrayList<String> grupoC = new ArrayList<String>(4);
static ArrayList<String> grupoD = new ArrayList<String>(4);
static ArrayList<String> grupoE = new ArrayList<String>(4);
static ArrayList<String> grupoF = new ArrayList<String>(4);
static ArrayList<String> grupoG = new ArrayList<String>(4);
static ArrayList<String> grupoH = new ArrayList<String>(4);

static ArrayList<String> bombo4 = new ArrayList();
static ArrayList<String> bombo3 = new ArrayList();
static ArrayList<String> bombo2 = new ArrayList();
static ArrayList<String> bombo1 = new ArrayList();

public static ArrayList llenarBombo1(){
    bombo1.add("Flamengo                        BRASIL");
    bombo1.add("River Plate                     ARGENTINA");
    bombo1.add("Palmeiras                       BRASIL");
    bombo1.add("Boca Juniors                    ARGENTINA");
    bombo1.add("Nacional                        URUGUAY");
    bombo1.add("Athletico Paranaense            BRASIL");
    bombo1.add("Independiente del Valle         ECUADOR");
    bombo1.add("Olimpia                         PARAGUAY");
    return bombo1;
}
public static ArrayList llenarBombo2(){
    bombo2.add("Libertad                        PARAGUAY");
    bombo2.add("Atletico Nacional               COLOMBIA");
    bombo2.add("Internacional                   BRASIL");
    bombo2.add("Barcelona                       ECUADOR");
    bombo2.add("Racing Club                     ARGENTINA");
    bombo2.add("Corinthians                     BRASIL");
    bombo2.add("Colo Colo                       CHILE");
    bombo2.add("Fluminense                      BRASIL");
    return bombo2;
}
public static ArrayList llenarBombo3(){       
    bombo3.add("Bolivar                         BOLIVIA");
    bombo3.add("The Strongest                   BOLIVIA");
    bombo3.add("Melgar                          PERU");
    bombo3.add("Alianza Lima                    PERU");
    bombo3.add("Argentinos Juniors              ARGENTINA");
    bombo3.add("Metropolitanos                  VENEZUELA");
    bombo3.add("Aucas                           ECUADOR");
    bombo3.add("Monagas                         VENEZUELA");
    return bombo3;
}
public static ArrayList llenarBombo4(){       
    bombo4.add("Liverpool                       URUGUAY");
    bombo4.add("Deportivo Pereira               COLOMBIA");
    bombo4.add("Nublense                        CHILE");
    bombo4.add("Patronato                       ARGENTINA");
    bombo4.add("Atletico Mineiro                BRASIL");
    bombo4.add("Sporting Cristal                PERU");
    bombo4.add("Cerro Porteno                   PARAGUAY");
    bombo4.add("Independiente Medellin          COLOMBIA");
    return bombo4;
}

static int equipo_bombo1;
static int equipo_bombo2;
static int equipo_bombo3;
static int equipo_bombo4;

public static void asignacionA(){
    equipo_bombo1 = (int) (Math.random()*(8-1))+1;
    equipo_bombo2 = (int) (Math.random()*(16-9))+9;
    equipo_bombo3 = (int) (Math.random()*(24-17))+17;
    equipo_bombo4 = (int) (Math.random()*(32-25))+25;
    
    switch (equipo_bombo1) {
        case 1:
            grupoA.add(bombo1.get(0));
            bombo1.remove(0);
            break;
        case 2:
            grupoA.add(bombo1.get(1));
            bombo1.remove(1);
            break;
        case 3:
            grupoA.add(bombo1.get(2));
            bombo1.remove(2);
            break;
        case 4:
            grupoA.add(bombo1.get(3));
            bombo1.remove(3);
            break;
        case 5:
            grupoA.add(bombo1.get(4));
            bombo1.remove(4);
            break;
        case 6:
            grupoA.add(bombo1.get(5));
            bombo1.remove(5);
            break;
        case 7:
            grupoA.add(bombo1.get(6));
            bombo1.remove(6);
            break;
        case 8:
            grupoA.add(bombo1.get(7));
            bombo1.remove(7);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo2) {
        case 9:
            grupoA.add(bombo2.get(0));
            bombo2.remove(0);
            break;
        case 10:
            grupoA.add(bombo2.get(1));
            bombo2.remove(1);
            break;
        case 11:
            grupoA.add(bombo2.get(2));
            bombo2.remove(2);
            break;
        case 12:
            grupoA.add(bombo2.get(3));
            bombo2.remove(3);
            break;
        case 13:
            grupoA.add(bombo2.get(4));
            bombo2.remove(4);
            break;
        case 14:
            grupoA.add(bombo2.get(5));
            bombo2.remove(5);
            break;
        case 15:
            grupoA.add(bombo2.get(6));
            bombo2.remove(6);
            break;
        case 16:
            grupoA.add(bombo2.get(7));
            bombo2.remove(7);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo3) {
        case 17:
            grupoA.add(bombo3.get(0));
            bombo3.remove(0);
            break;
        case 18:
            grupoA.add(bombo3.get(1));
            bombo3.remove(1);
            break;
        case 19:
            grupoA.add(bombo3.get(2));
            bombo3.remove(2);
            break;
        case 20:
            grupoA.add(bombo3.get(3));
            bombo3.remove(3);
            break;
        case 21:
            grupoA.add(bombo3.get(4));
            bombo3.remove(4);
            break;
        case 22:
            grupoA.add(bombo3.get(5));
            bombo3.remove(5);
            break;
        case 23:
            grupoA.add(bombo3.get(6));
            bombo3.remove(6);
            break;
        case 24:
            grupoA.add(bombo3.get(7));
            bombo3.remove(7);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo4) {
        case 25:
            grupoA.add(bombo4.get(0));
            bombo4.remove(0);
            break;
        case 26:
            grupoA.add(bombo4.get(1));
            bombo4.remove(1);
            break;
        case 27:
            grupoA.add(bombo4.get(2));
            bombo4.remove(2);
            break;
        case 28:
            grupoA.add(bombo4.get(3));
            bombo4.remove(3);
            break;
        case 29:
            grupoA.add(bombo4.get(4));
            bombo4.remove(4);
            break;
        case 30:
            grupoA.add(bombo4.get(5));
            bombo4.remove(5);
            break;
        case 31:
            grupoA.add(bombo4.get(6));
            bombo4.remove(6);
            break;
        case 32:
            grupoA.add(bombo4.get(7));
            bombo4.remove(7);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
public static void asignacionB(){
    equipo_bombo1 = (int) (Math.random()*(7-1))+1;
    equipo_bombo2 = (int) (Math.random()*(14-8))+8;
    equipo_bombo3 = (int) (Math.random()*(21-15))+15;
    equipo_bombo4 = (int) (Math.random()*(28-22))+22;
    
    switch (equipo_bombo1) {
        case 1:
            grupoB.add(bombo1.get(0));
            bombo1.remove(0);
            break;
        case 2:
            grupoB.add(bombo1.get(1));
            bombo1.remove(1);
            break;
        case 3:
            grupoB.add(bombo1.get(2));
            bombo1.remove(2);
            break;
        case 4:
            grupoB.add(bombo1.get(3));
            bombo1.remove(3);
            break;
        case 5:
            grupoB.add(bombo1.get(4));
            bombo1.remove(4);
            break;
        case 6:
            grupoB.add(bombo1.get(5));
            bombo1.remove(5);
            break;
        case 7:
            grupoB.add(bombo1.get(6));
            bombo1.remove(6);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo2) {
        case 8:
            grupoB.add(bombo2.get(0));
            bombo2.remove(0);
            break;
        case 9:
            grupoB.add(bombo2.get(1));
            bombo2.remove(1);
            break;
        case 10:
            grupoB.add(bombo2.get(2));
            bombo2.remove(2);
            break;
        case 11:
            grupoB.add(bombo2.get(3));
            bombo2.remove(3);
            break;
        case 12:
            grupoB.add(bombo2.get(4));
            bombo2.remove(4);
            break;
        case 13:
            grupoB.add(bombo2.get(5));
            bombo2.remove(5);
            break;
        case 14:
            grupoB.add(bombo2.get(6));
            bombo2.remove(6);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo3) {
        case 15:
            grupoB.add(bombo3.get(0));
            bombo3.remove(0);
            break;
        case 16:
            grupoB.add(bombo3.get(1));
            bombo3.remove(1);
            break;
        case 17:
            grupoB.add(bombo3.get(2));
            bombo3.remove(2);
            break;
        case 18:
            grupoB.add(bombo3.get(3));
            bombo3.remove(3);
            break;
        case 19:
            grupoB.add(bombo3.get(4));
            bombo3.remove(4);
            break;
        case 20:
            grupoB.add(bombo3.get(5));
            bombo3.remove(5);
            break;
        case 21:
            grupoB.add(bombo3.get(6));
            bombo3.remove(6);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo4) {
        case 22:
            grupoB.add(bombo4.get(0));
            bombo4.remove(0);
            break;
        case 23:
            grupoB.add(bombo4.get(1));
            bombo4.remove(1);
            break;
        case 24:
            grupoB.add(bombo4.get(2));
            bombo4.remove(2);
            break;
        case 25:
            grupoB.add(bombo4.get(3));
            bombo4.remove(3);
            break;
        case 26:
            grupoB.add(bombo4.get(4));
            bombo4.remove(4);
            break;
        case 27:
            grupoB.add(bombo4.get(5));
            bombo4.remove(5);
            break;
        case 28:
            grupoB.add(bombo4.get(6));
            bombo4.remove(6);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}   
public static void asignacionC(){
    equipo_bombo1 = (int) (Math.random()*(6-1))+1;
    equipo_bombo2 = (int) (Math.random()*(12-7))+7;
    equipo_bombo3 = (int) (Math.random()*(18-13))+13;
    equipo_bombo4 = (int) (Math.random()*(24-19))+19;
    
    switch (equipo_bombo1) {
        case 1:
            grupoC.add(bombo1.get(0));
            bombo1.remove(0);
            break;
        case 2:
            grupoC.add(bombo1.get(1));
            bombo1.remove(1);
            break;
        case 3:
            grupoC.add(bombo1.get(2));
            bombo1.remove(2);
            break;
        case 4:
            grupoC.add(bombo1.get(3));
            bombo1.remove(3);
            break;
        case 5:
            grupoC.add(bombo1.get(4));
            bombo1.remove(4);
            break;
        case 6:
            grupoC.add(bombo1.get(5));
            bombo1.remove(5);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo2) {
        case 7:
            grupoC.add(bombo2.get(0));
            bombo2.remove(0);
            break;
        case 8:
            grupoC.add(bombo2.get(1));
            bombo2.remove(1);
            break;
        case 9:
            grupoC.add(bombo2.get(2));
            bombo2.remove(2);
            break;
        case 10:
            grupoC.add(bombo2.get(3));
            bombo2.remove(3);
            break;
        case 11:
            grupoC.add(bombo2.get(4));
            bombo2.remove(4);
            break;
        case 12:
            grupoC.add(bombo2.get(5));
            bombo2.remove(5);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo3) {
        case 13:
            grupoC.add(bombo3.get(0));
            bombo3.remove(0);
            break;
        case 14:
            grupoC.add(bombo3.get(1));
            bombo3.remove(1);
            break;
        case 15:
            grupoC.add(bombo3.get(2));
            bombo3.remove(2);
            break;
        case 16:
            grupoC.add(bombo3.get(3));
            bombo3.remove(3);
            break;
        case 17:
            grupoC.add(bombo3.get(4));
            bombo3.remove(4);
            break;
        case 18:
            grupoC.add(bombo3.get(5));
            bombo3.remove(5);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo4) {
        case 19:
            grupoC.add(bombo4.get(0));
            bombo4.remove(0);
            break;
        case 20:
            grupoC.add(bombo4.get(1));
            bombo4.remove(1);
            break;
        case 21:
            grupoC.add(bombo4.get(2));
            bombo4.remove(2);
            break;
        case 22:
            grupoC.add(bombo4.get(3));
            bombo4.remove(3);
            break;
        case 23:
            grupoC.add(bombo4.get(4));
            bombo4.remove(4);
            break;
        case 24:
            grupoC.add(bombo4.get(5));
            bombo4.remove(5);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}   
public static void asignacionD(){
    equipo_bombo1 = (int) (Math.random()*(5-1))+1;
    equipo_bombo2 = (int) (Math.random()*(10-6))+6;
    equipo_bombo3 = (int) (Math.random()*(15-11))+11;
    equipo_bombo4 = (int) (Math.random()*(20-16))+16;
    
    switch (equipo_bombo1) {
        case 1:
            grupoD.add(bombo1.get(0));
            bombo1.remove(0);
            break;
        case 2:
            grupoD.add(bombo1.get(1));
            bombo1.remove(1);
            break;
        case 3:
            grupoD.add(bombo1.get(2));
            bombo1.remove(2);
            break;
        case 4:
            grupoD.add(bombo1.get(3));
            bombo1.remove(3);
            break;
        case 5:
            grupoD.add(bombo1.get(4));
            bombo1.remove(4);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo2) {
        case 6:
            grupoD.add(bombo2.get(0));
            bombo2.remove(0);
            break;
        case 7:
            grupoD.add(bombo2.get(1));
            bombo2.remove(1);
            break;
        case 8:
            grupoD.add(bombo2.get(2));
            bombo2.remove(2);
            break;
        case 9:
            grupoD.add(bombo2.get(3));
            bombo2.remove(3);
            break;
        case 10:
            grupoD.add(bombo2.get(4));
            bombo2.remove(4);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo3) {
        case 11:
            grupoD.add(bombo3.get(0));
            bombo3.remove(0);
            break;
        case 12:
            grupoD.add(bombo3.get(1));
            bombo3.remove(1);
            break;
        case 13:
            grupoD.add(bombo3.get(2));
            bombo3.remove(2);
            break;
        case 14:
            grupoD.add(bombo3.get(3));
            bombo3.remove(3);
            break;
        case 15:
            grupoD.add(bombo3.get(4));
            bombo3.remove(4);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo4) {
        case 16:
            grupoD.add(bombo4.get(0));
            bombo4.remove(0);
            break;
        case 17:
            grupoD.add(bombo4.get(1));
            bombo4.remove(1);
            break;
        case 18:
            grupoD.add(bombo4.get(2));
            bombo4.remove(2);
            break;
        case 19:
            grupoD.add(bombo4.get(3));
            bombo4.remove(3);
            break;
        case 20:
            grupoD.add(bombo4.get(4));
            bombo4.remove(4);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
public static void asignacionE(){
    equipo_bombo1 = (int) (Math.random()*(4-1))+1;
    equipo_bombo2 = (int) (Math.random()*(8-5))+5;
    equipo_bombo3 = (int) (Math.random()*(12-9))+9;
    equipo_bombo4 = (int) (Math.random()*(16-13))+13;
    
    switch (equipo_bombo1) {
        case 1:
            grupoE.add(bombo1.get(0));
            bombo1.remove(0);
            break;
        case 2:
            grupoE.add(bombo1.get(1));
            bombo1.remove(1);
            break;
        case 3:
            grupoE.add(bombo1.get(2));
            bombo1.remove(2);
            break;
        case 4:
            grupoE.add(bombo1.get(3));
            bombo1.remove(3);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo2) {
        case 5:
            grupoE.add(bombo2.get(0));
            bombo2.remove(0);
            break;
        case 6:
            grupoE.add(bombo2.get(1));
            bombo2.remove(1);
            break;
        case 7:
            grupoE.add(bombo2.get(2));
            bombo2.remove(2);
            break;
        case 8:
            grupoE.add(bombo2.get(3));
            bombo2.remove(3);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo3) {
        case 9:
            grupoE.add(bombo3.get(0));
            bombo3.remove(0);
            break;
        case 10:
            grupoE.add(bombo3.get(1));
            bombo3.remove(1);
            break;
        case 11:
            grupoE.add(bombo3.get(2));
            bombo3.remove(2);
            break;
        case 12:
            grupoE.add(bombo3.get(3));
            bombo3.remove(3);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo4) {
        case 13:
            grupoE.add(bombo4.get(0));
            bombo4.remove(0);
            break;
        case 14:
            grupoE.add(bombo4.get(1));
            bombo4.remove(1);
            break;
        case 15:
            grupoE.add(bombo4.get(2));
            bombo4.remove(2);
            break;
        case 16:
            grupoE.add(bombo4.get(3));
            bombo4.remove(3);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
public static void asignacionF(){
    equipo_bombo1 = (int) (Math.random()*(3-1))+1;
    equipo_bombo2 = (int) (Math.random()*(6-4))+4;
    equipo_bombo3 = (int) (Math.random()*(9-7))+7;
    equipo_bombo4 = (int) (Math.random()*(12-10))+10;
    
    switch (equipo_bombo1) {
        case 1:
            grupoF.add(bombo1.get(0));
            bombo1.remove(0);
            break;
        case 2:
            grupoF.add(bombo1.get(1));
            bombo1.remove(1);
            break;
        case 3:
            grupoF.add(bombo1.get(2));
            bombo1.remove(2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo2) {
        case 4:
            grupoF.add(bombo2.get(0));
            bombo2.remove(0);
            break;
        case 5:
            grupoF.add(bombo2.get(1));
            bombo2.remove(1);
            break;
        case 6:
            grupoF.add(bombo2.get(2));
            bombo2.remove(2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo3) {
        case 7:
            grupoF.add(bombo3.get(0));
            bombo3.remove(0);
            break;
        case 8:
            grupoF.add(bombo3.get(1));
            bombo3.remove(1);
            break;
        case 9:
            grupoF.add(bombo3.get(2));
            bombo3.remove(2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo4) {
        case 10:
            grupoF.add(bombo4.get(0));
            bombo4.remove(0);
            break;
        case 11:
            grupoF.add(bombo4.get(1));
            bombo4.remove(1);
            break;
        case 12:
            grupoF.add(bombo4.get(2));
            bombo4.remove(2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
public static void asignacionG(){
    equipo_bombo1 = (int) (Math.random()*(2-1))+1;
    equipo_bombo2 = (int) (Math.random()*(4-3))+3;
    equipo_bombo3 = (int) (Math.random()*(6-5))+5;
    equipo_bombo4 = (int) (Math.random()*(8-7))+7;
    
    switch (equipo_bombo1) {
        case 1:
            grupoG.add(bombo1.get(0));
            bombo1.remove(0);
            break;
        case 2:
            grupoG.add(bombo1.get(1));
            bombo1.remove(1);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo2) {
        case 3:
            grupoG.add(bombo2.get(0));
            bombo2.remove(0);
            break;
        case 4:
            grupoG.add(bombo2.get(1));
            bombo2.remove(1);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo3) {
        case 5:
            grupoG.add(bombo3.get(0));
            bombo3.remove(0);
            break;
        case 6:
            grupoG.add(bombo3.get(1));
            bombo3.remove(1);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo4) {
        case 7:
            grupoG.add(bombo4.get(0));
            bombo4.remove(0);
            break;
        case 8:
            grupoG.add(bombo4.get(1));
            bombo4.remove(1);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
public static void asignacionH(){
    equipo_bombo1 = (int) (Math.random()*(1-1))+1;
    equipo_bombo2 = (int) (Math.random()*(2-2))+2;
    equipo_bombo3 = (int) (Math.random()*(3-3))+3;
    equipo_bombo4 = (int) (Math.random()*(4-4))+4;
    
    switch (equipo_bombo1) {
        case 1:
            grupoH.add(bombo1.get(0));
            bombo1.remove(0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo2) {
        case 2:
            grupoH.add(bombo2.get(0));
            bombo2.remove(0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo3) {
        case 3:
            grupoH.add(bombo3.get(0));
            bombo3.remove(0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    switch (equipo_bombo4) {
        case 4:
            grupoH.add(bombo4.get(0));
            bombo4.remove(0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


public static void imprimirA(){
    System.out.println("Grupo A:");
    Iterator it = grupoA.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    System.out.println(it.next());
    System.out.print("\n");
}
public static void imprimirB(){
    System.out.println("Grupo B:");
    Iterator it = grupoB.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    System.out.println(it.next());
    System.out.print("\n");
}
public static void imprimirC(){
    System.out.println("Grupo C:");
    Iterator it = grupoC.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    System.out.println(it.next());
    System.out.print("\n");
}
public static void imprimirD(){
    System.out.println("Grupo D:");
    Iterator it = grupoD.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    System.out.println(it.next());
    System.out.print("\n");
}
public static void imprimirE(){
    System.out.println("Grupo E:");
    Iterator it = grupoE.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    System.out.println(it.next());
    System.out.print("\n");
}
public static void imprimirF(){
    System.out.println("Grupo F:");
    Iterator it = grupoF.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    System.out.println(it.next());
    System.out.print("\n");
}
public static void imprimirG(){
    System.out.println("Grupo G:");
    Iterator it = grupoG.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    System.out.println(it.next());
    System.out.print("\n");
}
public static void imprimirH(){
    System.out.println("Grupo H:");
    Iterator it = grupoH.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    System.out.println(it.next());
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: una idea seria aplicar el paradigma de la programacion orientada a objetos, crear una clase "Equipo" con atributos nombreDeEquipo,paisDeEquipo,fase de esa manera aplicar las condicionales en base a esos atributos

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Equipo {
    String pais;
    String nombre;
    int bombo;
    String grupo;
    String ingresoPor;

    public Equipo( String nom, String pai, String ing, int bom ) {
        pais = pai;
        nombre = nom;
        ingresoPor = ing;
        bombo = bom;
    }

    public String getPais() {
        return pais;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getIngreso() {
       return nombre;
    }

    public int getBombo() {
        return bombo;
    }

    public String getGrupo() {
        return grupo;
    }

    public void setGrupo( String gru ) {
        grupo = gru;
    }
}

public class Grupo {
   List<Equipo> equipos = new ArrayList<>();
   List<String> paises = new ArrayList<>();

   public String estaPais( String pais ) {
      if( paises.contains( pais )) {
         return buscarEquipoPorPais( pais ).getIngreso();
      }
      return "no";
   }
   
   Equipo buscarEquipoPorPais( String pais ) {
      for( int i = 0; i < equipos.size(); i++ ) {
         if( equipos.get( i ).getPais().equals( pais )) {
            return equipos.get( i );
         }         
      }
       return equipos.get( 0 );   
   } 

   public void agregaEquipo( Equipo equ ) {
      equipos.add( equ );
   }

   public List<Equipo> getEquipos() {
      return equipos;
   }
}


public class Principal {

       // la lista tiene: nombre, pais, tipo de ingreso, numero de bombo
    String listaEquipos[] = {
        "Flamengo,BRASIL,fasePrevia,1",
        "River Plate,ARGENTINA,otra,1",
        "Palmeiras,BRASIL,otra,1",
        "Boca Juniors,ARGENTINA,fasePrevia,1"
    };

    Equipo equipos[] = new Equipo[ listaEquipos.length ];
    List <List <Equipo>> bombos = new ArrayList<>();

    void crearEquipos() {
        for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
            bombos.add( new ArrayList<>() );
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < listaEquipos.length; i++ ) {
              // creas un array del texto
            String subList[] = listaEquipos[ i ].split( "," );
            int bombo = Integer.parseInt( subList[3] );

              // creas el equipo
            equipos[ i ] = new Equipo( subList[0], subList[1], subList[2], bombo );

              // metes el equipo en el bombo que le corresponde
            bombos.get( bombo ).add( equipos[ i ] );
        }
    }
}

void llenarGrupos() {
   for( int i = 0; i < grupos.length; i++ ) {
      int ingresados = 0;
      while( ingresados < 8 ) {
        
          // un aleatorio para elejir el bombo y otro para el equipo dentro del mismo
         int bombo = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
         int numeroDeEquipo = (int) ( Math.random() * 8 );            
         Equipo equipo = bombos.get( bombo ).get( numeroDeEquipo );
        
          // tomamos el pais del equipo y luego comprobamos si está en el grupo
         String pais = equipo.getPais();
         String esta = grupos[ i ].estaPais( pais );            
        
          // si el equipo ingreso por fasePrevia, se carga
          // si el pais no está en el grupo, se carga
          // si el equipo que ya está ingreso por fasePrevia, se carga
         if( equipo.getIngreso().equals( "fasePrevia" ) || esta.equals( "no" ) || esta.equals( "fasePrevia" )) {
            grupos[ i ].agregaEquipo( equipo );
            ingresados++;
         }            
      }         
   }  

   void mostrarGrupos() {
      for( int i = 0; i < grupos.length; i++ ) {
         System.out.println( grupos[ i ].getEquipos() );         
      }
   }  

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Principal pri = new Principal ();
      pri.crearEquipos();
      pri.llenarGrupos();
      pri.mostrarGrupos();
      System.out.println( pri.equipos[ 0 ].getNombre() );
   }
}
```

Lo fantástico de poder pasarle parámetros a los métodos, es que no necesitamos repetir código, y las clases, nos evitan llevar una enorme cantidad de variables, declaramos un array de objetos, y los tenemos todos en una sola variable...
Tenemos la clase **Equipo** que es un contenedor de datos, al que le podemos solicitar los mismos.
La clase **Grupo**, que tiene un método para agregar equipos, y otro que nos devuelve "no" si el pais por el que se pregunta está en el grupo, y sino, nos devuelve el tipo de ingreso.
La clase **Principal**, es el obrero, el que hace todo el trabajo.
En ella tenemos la lista de equipos, con la cual creamos los objetos del tipo **Equipo**, y los coloca en su respectivo "bombo".
Luego está el método **llenarGrupos**, que se encarga de cargar en cada grupo los equipos correspondientes, y el **mostrarGrupos**, que no necesita explicación...
No he podido probarlo, porqué no me voy a poner a crear la lista de equipos (vago yo???!!!), así que si hay algo que no funcione, me avisas.